# Auto CC on outbound SMTP mail

Tags: smtp

Is there a way to have IIS SMTP mail server automatically CC all mail it sends to a fixed email address?  Now, when Chilkat mail sends messages via SMTP, there is no record of the sent messages.  We would like to CC a common mailbox with all these messages to create an easy to use log of the messages that have been sent.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the IIS6 logfiles contain records of sent email? You may be able to enable extended logging or diagnostic logging in IIS6? I don't have a server handy, or I'd try it out.. :)